# Specific key on my keyboard highlights text

Tags: windows-10

I'm having a weird issue with my keys configuration on Windows 10.
Yesterday, I was typing in notepad, and then my 'w' key started to highlight everything, so whenever I press it, I have text highlighted instead of writing 'w'.
I might have pressed multiple keys, which resulted to change 'w' action.
Anyways, I don't find any resource online for this, and it's pretty much annoying to use the clipboard for a character.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It might be `WASD` keys are changed with `Arrows Keys`

WASD keys for Arrows Keys

`W` for ⬆
`A` for ⬅
`S` for ⬇
`D` for ➡

There are shortcut keys to enable and disable `WASD` keys.

- Fn + W
- Fn + E (for 5 secs)
- Fn + Esc
- Fn + Left Key ⬅

Note: `Fn` is the function key